# Why do I get "no match for ‘operator=’" for custom class if I'm not overloading?

Tags: c++, g++

I've Googled around and discovered questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046323/why-am-i-getting-error-no-match-for-operator-inside-function) or [that one](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/5426/), but none seems to have had the same problem I do. Searching for the error (`no match for ‘operator=’`) and the note (`no known conversion for argument 1`) yields few results.

I'm building a Datalog parser, and classes for Parameter and Expression need each other as members. I think I've implemented the forward declaration correctly, but I could still have a problem there. Below I've done my best to minimally reproduce the error.

**parameter.h**

```
#ifndef PARAMETER_H
#define PARAMETER_H


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Expression;

class Parameter {
   public:
    explicit Parameter(std::string&);
    explicit Parameter(Expression*);
    std::string str;
    Expression* e;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Parameter&);
};

class Expression {
   public:
    Expression(Parameter&, std::string&, Parameter&);
    Parameter l;
    std::string op;
    Parameter r;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Expression&);
};

#endif  // PARAMETER_H
```

**parameter.cpp**

```
#include "parameter.h"

Parameter::Parameter(std::string& param) : str(param) {}

Parameter::Parameter(Expression* expr) { e = expr; }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, const Parameter& p) {
    if (p.str.empty()) {
        // parameter is an expression
        strm << *p.e;
    } else {
        // parameter is ID or STRING
        strm << p.str;
    }

    return strm;
}

Expression::Expression(Parameter& left, std::string& oper, Parameter& right) : l(left), op(oper), r(right) {}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, const Expression& e) {
    strm << "(" << e.l << " " << e.op << " " << e.r << ")";

    return strm;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "parameter.h"

int main() {
    std::string sample1 = "word";
    std::string sample2 = "another";
    std::string sample3 = "yep";

    std::vector<std::string> samples;
    samples.push_back(sample1);
    samples.push_back(sample2);
    samples.push_back(sample3);

    std::vector<Parameter> params;

    params.insert(params.end(), samples.begin(), samples.end());

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using `gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)`. Compiling with `g++ -Wall -Werror -std=c++17 -g *.cpp` gives the following:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
             from recursiveDescent.h:4,
             from recursiveDescent.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘static _OI 
std::__copy_move<false, false, 
std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*; _OI = Parameter*]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:386:44:   required from 
[...skipped...] required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:324:18: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Parameter’ and ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’)
    *__result = *__first;
    ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from predicate.h:8:0,
                 from datalogProgram.h:8,
                 from recursiveDescent.h:8,
                 from recursiveDescent.cpp:1:
parameter.h:10:7: note: candidate: Parameter& Parameter::operator=(const Parameter&)
 class Parameter {
   ^~~~~~~~~
parameter.h:10:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const Parameter&’
parameter.h:10:7: note: candidate: Parameter& Parameter::operator=(Parameter&&)
parameter.h:10:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘Parameter&&’
```

Comment: You haven't shown the line of code that produces the error. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It looks like somewhere outside the code provided you are trying to assign a `std::string` to a `Parameter`. You can't do that unless you have a function that allows you to make a `Parameter` from a `string`. The error message is the compiler trying to make the `=` operator fit and can't.

Comment: Oh man, that was probably it. I think I just found the offending line. I'll post a minimal example in a sec

Comment: done. This makes it glaringly obvious I guess.

Comment: just as a note in general when you're taking parameters as `T&` just to copy them then I would advise to at least take them as `const T&` if you're not modifying them.

Answer (score 0):

OP's constructor `Parameter::Parameter(std::string&)` (or, as PeterT pointed out, better `Parameter::Parameter(const std::string&)`) could (and would) be used for implicit conversion of `std::string` to `Parameter` in

```
params.insert(params.end(), samples.begin(), samples.end());
```

but OP explicitly prohibited this by making it `explicit`.

I use the `explicit` often for constructors which can be called with one argument because I'm afraid of accidental conversions (and I'd like the illusion of having control over my code). In this case, it might be easier to drop the `explicit`.

Sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Parameter {
  private:
    std::string _name;
  public:
    /*explicit*/ Parameter(const std::string &name): _name(name) { }
    const std::string& name() const { return _name; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Parameter &param)
{
  return out << "Parameter '" << param.name() << "'";
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::vector<T> &vec)
{
  const char *sep = "";
  for (const T &elem : vec) {
    out << sep << elem;
    sep = ", ";
  }
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  const std::vector<std::string> samples({ "word", "another", "yep" });
  std::vector<Parameter> params;
  params.insert(params.end(), samples.begin(), samples.end());
  std::cout << "params: " << params << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
params: Parameter 'word', Parameter 'another', Parameter 'yep'
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca7eeb87aee35d69)</kbd>

Comment: Good point. That'll teach me to blindly follow the linter's advice next time

Comment: @KyleRoth I wouldn't trust hints of a machine too much. Simple typos may confuse the compiler completely and cause cascades of errors which are not really helpful. (Have you ever forgot to close a namespace in a header?) But sometimes, I'm really impressed about the hints `g++` provides in certain situations like e.g. in this: [SO: Dynamic Array Template Class: problem with ostream& operator friend function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54018483/7478597).